# reactjs: after action redux not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I have a question, regarding updating a status in redux, I have this code that lists me a few elements and works well, now when I delete one of those elements also works, but the list is not updated after the delete click, I have to reload the page, to see the changes, some guide

// Component listcomponent.js

```
export default class listcomponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderGroup()}
      </div>
    )
  }
   renderGroup(){
    return this.props.allList.map((item, index)=>{
      return(
          <div className="panel panel-success tour-item-list">
              <h3 className="panel-title">{item.name} </h3>
              <div onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(item.key)}>delete</div>
        </div>  
      )
    })
  }
  handleDelete(key){
      this.props.deleteGroup(key, function(err,res){
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
        }else{
          console.log(res);

        }
      })
    }
  }
```

//container -->join listcomponent.js with action

```
import {getListGroup} from './action/listGroup.js';
import {deleteGroup} from './action/deleteGroup.js';
import listcomponent from './listcomponent.jsx'
class ListContainer extends Component{
  componentDidMount(){
      this.props.getListGroup();
      this.props.deleteGroup();
    } 
    render (){
        return (
                <listcomponent allList={this.props.allList} deleteGroup={this.props.deleteGroup} />
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(store) {
  return {
    allList: store.allList
  };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    getListGroup: getListGroup,
    deleteGroup: deleteGroup
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(ListContainer);
```

//reducer ---> listReducer.js

```
export const listReducer = (state=[], action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_GROUP_REQUEST':
      return state;
    case 'GET_GROUP_FAILURE':
      return state;
    case 'GET_GROUP_SUCCESS':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case 'DELETE_GROUP_SUCCESS':    
        const idToDelete = action.payload;
          return state.filter((item) => {
             item.tour_groups[0].tour_group_key !== idToDelete
         });
    default:
      return state;     
  }
}
```

// general reducer --> reducer.js

```
 export default import { listReducer } from './listReducer.js'

    const reducers = combineReducers({
      allGroup:listGroupReducer

})
```

// store --> store.js

```
import reducers from './reducer.js';

const store = createStore(
  reducers, 
   applyMiddleware(thunk,  logger())
)
```

// service to edit --getlistgroup.js

```
export const deleteGroup = (tour_group_key, callback)=>{    
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch({type:'DELETE_GROUP_REQUEST'});
        axios.delete('x/v1/user/tour_groups/'+tour_group_key)
        .then((response)=>{
            dispatch({type:'DELETE_GROUP_SUCCESS', payload:tour_group_key});
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(null, response.data);
            }
        })
        .catch((response)=>{
            dispatch({type:'DELETE_GROUP_FAILURE'})
            if(typeof callback ==='function'){
                callback(response.data, null)
            }   
        })
    } 
}
```

// service to list -->listgroup.js

```
export const getListGroup = (callback)=>{
        return function(dispatch){
            dispatch({type:'GET_GROUP_REQUEST'});
            axios.get('x/v1/user/tour_groups')
            .then((response)=>{
                dispatch({type:'GET_GROUP_SUCCESS', payload:response.data});
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback(null, response.data);
                }
            })
            .catch((response)=>{
                dispatch({type:'GET_GROUP_FAILURE'})
                if(typeof callback ==='function'){
                    callback(error.response.data, null)
                }   
            })
        } 
    }
```

// the service i call

```
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "count": 2,
  "tour_groups": [
    {
      "tour_guide": "ahpkZXZ-c3RyZWV0dG91ci1kZXZlbG9wbWVudHIRCxIEVXNlchiAgICAgICACQw",
      "description": "asfease",
      "name": "fefe",
      "tour_group_key": "ahpkZXZ-c3RyZWV0dG91ci1kZXZlbG9wbWVudHInCxIEVXNlchiAgICAgICACQwLEglUb3VyR3JvdXAYgICAgIDwuwkM"
    },
    {
      "tour_guide": "ahpkZXZ-c3RyZWV0dG91ci1kZXZlbG9wbWVudHIRCxIEVXNlchiAgICAgICACQw",
      "description": "ente",
      "name": "pariente",
      "tour_group_key": "ahpkZXZ-c3RyZWV0dG91ci1kZXZlbG9wbWVudHInCxIEVXNlchiAgICAgICACQwLEglUb3VyR3JvdXAYgICAgIDwuwgM"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you dispatch an action with your action creator to delete the item? E.g. do you have a reducer that handles a type such as DELETE_ITEM?

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, yes i have the action for delete: export const deleteGroup = (data, callback)=>{ 
 return function(dispatch){
  dispatch({type:'DELETE_GROUP_REQUEST'});
  axios.delete('x/v1/user/tour_groups/'+data)
  .then((response)=>{
   dispatch({type:'DELETE_GROUP_SUCCESS', payload:response.data});
   if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(null, response.data);
   }
  })
  .catch((response)=>{
   dispatch({type:'DELETE_GROUP_FAILURE'})
 
  })
 } 
}

Comment: Can you show me where you handle the DELETE_GROUP_SUCCESS?

Comment: in the reducer?

Comment: Yes, in the reducer

Comment: not, for edit, i dont have reducer, justh with listReducer

Comment: That is why your list doesn't update. You have to manually tell redux that your state has changed. View my answer and let me know if it worked

Answer (score 1):

You must handle a DELETE action in your reducers, otherwise redux doesn't know that your state has been updated. In other words:

Your Reducer

```
export const listReducer = (state=[], action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_GROUP_REQUEST':
      return state;
    case 'GET_GROUP_FAILURE':
      return state;
    case 'GET_GROUP_SUCCESS':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case 'DELETE_GROUP_SUCCESS':
      const idToDelete = action.payload;
      return state.filter((item) => {
          item.id !== idToDelete
      });
    default:
      return state;     
  }
}
```

Your Action Creator:

```
export const deleteGroup = (id, callback)=>{  
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch({type:'DELETE_GROUP_REQUEST'});
        axios.delete('x/v1/user/tour_groups/'+id)
        .then((response)=>{
            dispatch({type:'DELETE_GROUP_SUCCESS', payload: id});
        })
        .catch((response)=>{
            dispatch({type:'DELETE_GROUP_FAILURE'})
        })
    } 
}
```

Please note that 'id' in the reducer must match the key of the object in your state array. Hence if the items in your array look like this:

```
[ {
    user_id: '12',
    profile: {...}
  },
  ...
]
```

You must make sure to use:

```
return state.filter((item) => {
    item.user_id !== idToDelete
});
```

If your items are simply a flat array of strings then I recommend you refactor how your state looks. Also, I am not familiar with passing callbacks into your action creator, but I'm almost certain that is not good practice.

**EDIT**: based on your code your DELETE_GROUP_SUCCESS case is wrong. *Note: this assumes that you have a combineReducers call.

```
case 'DELETE_GROUP_SUCCESS':    
    const idToDelete = action.payload;
    return state.filter((tourGroup) => {
        tourGroup.tour_group_key !== idToDelete
    });
```

Comment: hi, i change mi reducer, but when re-render remove all the item to the list

Comment: Can you add the action creator to your original question? I need to see the contents of deleteGroup()

Comment: Okay I updated my answer, hopefully that helps, otherwise you will need to send me a sample repo where I can help you with your problem

Comment: hi, not work the list remove all the items, i update with the json and i made  the changes you send me, can you check

Comment: Its' hard to tell what your state actually looks like, but based on what I see your function is only handling the "tour_groups": [] portion of your state, because it is array based, if that is your only reducer you are not handling the state properly.

Comment: But I do not understand this part to which you mean, I made the return changes, but it is still the same by removing all the items, look my combine reducer up, its fine?