# setState not rendering with immutable

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, immutable.js

i have this code
Its function is to search and filter, the data come from this.props.allList, but it does not work I think the error is in the state but I'm not sure

// component.jsx
   'use strict';

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PureRenderMixin from 'react-addons-pure-render-mixin'; 
import Immutable from 'immutable';    


export default class ListComponent extends Component { 

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      allList: Immutable.List(),
      filteredData: Immutable.List(),
    };
    this.shouldComponentUpdate = PureRenderMixin.shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this);

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ 
      allList: Immutable.fromJS(this.props.allList).toList(),
      filteredData: Immutable.fromJS(this.props.allList).toList() 
    });
  }

  filterData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const regex = new RegExp(event.target.value, 'i');
    const filtered = this.state.allList.filter(function(datum) {
      return (datum.get('name').search(regex) > -1);
    });

    this.setState({
      filteredData: filtered,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { filteredData } = this.state;
    const prettyRows = filteredData.map(function(datum) {
        return (
        <tr>
      <td>{ datum.get("status") }{datum.status}</td>
      <td>{ datum.get("count") }{datum.count}</td>
    </tr>
   );

    });
    return(
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          onChange={ this.filterData.bind(this) }
          placeholder="Search" />
        <table
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>id </th>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            { prettyRows }
          </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>);
   }
 }
```

the json

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "tours": [
    {
       "title": "item 1",
    },
    {
       "title": "item 2",
    },
    {
       "title": "item 3",
    },

  ]
}
```

here the codepen: http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/WROpeg
thanks for your help

Comment: Is this an exact copy of your code? If so there is unreachable code in your render method. After you declared `{ filteredData } = this.state;` you have a `return ( ) ` wrapping the map function so the code stops executing and returns that map. as whats to be rendered

Comment: Sorry I have bad the render here, and modify the code but the same still does not render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first thing I noticed in your code is that you are using React.render,

   `React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));`

   this should be **ReactDOM**.render [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html)
2. Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/kfitzi/pen/qRjmyQ?editors=1010) with a working version of your code without Immutable.
3. Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/kfitzi/pen/RKggYK?editors=1010) with Immutable working.

notes:
Only the List is an Immutable structure, not the objects therein, so you do not have to use datam.get('name'), datam.name works.

4. "I need the states, to be able to do the crud, list, modify, eliminate"
   I think what you are saying is that you want to use react component state so that the filtering is performed at the component ui level, while maintaining the original full list of options (data) in the store? If your goal is to keep store state minimal, your data flow should probably look like this:

   1. **Action** dispatched in Component ->
      Store is updated if necessary ->
   2. **Reducer** returns the part of the store 
      with the relevant information ->
   3. **Selector** performs computations on data and returns 
      filtered/reduced/computed data to the view. 
      notes: [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) is a good tool for this.

This helps your maintain your store as the 'single source of truth', and keeps your components 'dry'.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help: i think that is not the problem, the problem I think comes in as I put the json in the state

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, It was actually what I was looking for, now I have another question, when I pass this to my test environment, I get the data from redux, and kepp it in the store, but that way it does not work for me, if I do console.log (this. Props.list) loads me, but if I do console.log (this.state.list) does not load me, you know why it can be

Comment: Yeah no worries. Usually when you are using a store, you minimize how much you use state in React components. I would have to see your code, but some tools I find really helpful are [React Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) and [Redux Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) if you aren't already using them. Also if you want to share your project [webpackbin](http://www.webpackbin.com/4J-FQVa-M) is pretty robust.

Comment: hi, look mi proyect is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750483/reactjs-after-action-redux-not-re-render

Comment: Quick question, why do you need to use state if your store is working correctly?

Comment: because I need the states, to be able to do the crud, list, modify, eliminate

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be caused by the variable `prettyRows`. The issue could be due to no variable `datum.get("status"), or datum.status`.

Would you be able to provide more information such as the errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have no errors, if I put console.log (this.props.allList) brings me the json well, but at the time of the render does not work

Comment: Question: If you are calling `{datum.status}` inside your mapped item why would you need to use `{ datum.get("status") }`? data.status should already be the value if I remember correctly.

Maybe add a debugger or console.log under datum to check what values are trying to get returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your react includes are wrong:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjwwMq

- remove "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-with-addons.min.js" -> that is a version mismatch with react 0.13 you are using as core
- comment `this.shouldComponentUpdate = PureRenderMixin.shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this);` because that does not work anymore

et voile

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but the filter dont work yet